# What is the Genaralized Pigeonhole Principle? Explain in your own words

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

My words:It is the least possible number that one can get when placing objects into boxes, given that the number of objects is greater than the number of boxes.

Did my wordings correct?

Comment: I would say no.  Try instead something more precise, such as "If $n$ objects are placed into $k$ boxes, then there is at least one box containing at least $\lceil n/k \rceil$ objects"

Answer (score 0):

If there's $n$ containers to hold $kn+1$ objects, then no matter how you distribute them, at least one container will have $k+1$ or more objects.